# ¿Como re direccionar desde UpdateView a DetailView despues de actualizar los datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

Entiendo que la clase `UpdateView` posee un atributo `success_url` donde habitualmente se incluye algo como `success_url = reverse_lazy('app:view-list')`

Lo que estoy buscando, es la forma de que se redirecciones a la vista `DetailView` del objeto al momento de registrar los cambios. Por lo que se, no podría hacerlo de la forma `success_url = reverse_lazy('app:view-detail')` porque se requiere la clave o slug del objeto.

**¿En que método correspondería y como se debe sobrescribirlo?**

Answer (score 1):

El método es `get_success_url()`. Sin embargo, lo que te recomiendo, así como recomienda también [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url), es tener el método `get_absolute_url()` en la definición de tu modelo.

**models.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse


class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ... todos tus campos
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app:view-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}))
```

De esta manera, tu `UpdateView` deducirá automáticamente adónde ir, **siempre y cuando no le indiques una `success_url` de manera manual**.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from .models import MyModel

 
class MyModelUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'tu/template.html'    # <-- La template de donde haces el update, NO la template de la success_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo no he trabajado con Django, pero deberia haber un metodo  parecido a laravel:

```
return back();
```

en tu controlador, cuando se ejecute el guardado de los datos entonces que te redireccione a la pagina anterior o mas bien a la misma pagina pero refrescada, no se si me explico.